# How To fix Error: options.uri is a required argument?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a CORS POST request, but it's giving this error:

Error: options.uri is a required argument

Here's my code:

```js
var express = require('express');  
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
var gg = false;
var gg2 = false;
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var url = req.url.substr(1);
 req.headers = {};
 req.headers['Host'] = "*";
 req.header['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
 req.header['User-Agent'] = 'iPad\r\n';
 req.header['Accept'] = '*/*';
 req.header['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br';
 req.header['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
 res.header('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
 // console.log(url);
 var proxy = request(url);
 proxy.on('data', function(data) {
  gg = data;
  gg2 = url;
  console.log('Proxy data: url: ' + url + "\n" + data); 
 });
 req.pipe(proxy);
 proxy.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: Which `request` version are you using?

Comment: "request": "~2.85.0"

Answer (score 1):

> Error: options.uri is a required argument

This error is possible, if the url you provide turns out to be a falsy value.

```
  // A URI is needed by this point, emit error if we haven't been able to get one
  if (!self.uri) {
    return self.emit('error', new Error('options.uri is a required argument'))
}
```

**Source code** : [link](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L232)

You can log the url and check the value